# Socket Receiving Wrong Data

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have server written in C/C++, and the client is in Java which is running on android.

The server look like

**C++ server**

```
#define ETH_DATA_LENGTH 25

 bzero(buf,ETH_DATA_LENGTH);
 rd=read(newsockfd,buf,ETH_DATA_LENGTH);

      if(rd>0){
       printf("received %s\n", buf);
       char cmd[ETH_DATA_LENGTH]={0};
       sprintf(cmd,"%s",buf);
       //setCommand(cmd);
       }
```

The android client send data packet of format  `5_11_14_, 5_11_15_, 5_11_16_,etc...` and the server receives the data correctly if there is a delay in client side with in each packet. But when the client send continuously I am getting some extra character and look like

```
received 5_11_9_

received 5_11_10_
5_11_11_
5_11_12�ڳ
received _

received 5_11_13_
```

And on the android side I am sending the data like

**Java client**

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientsocket.getOutputStream())),true);
out.println(str);
```

Any idea why this happening ?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You have not terminated your buffer before using it as a string, as your read may overwrite the last zero.  Also, you cannot expect data to come out of a TCP receive side necessarily in the same size pieces it went into the transmit side.

Comment: The 25 is too small, the length of "5_11_10_\r5_11_11_\r5_11_12" is 25. You need change the line to  `rd=read(newsockfd,buf,ETH_DATA_LENGTH - 1);`

Comment: @ ZijingWu Actually the client send data like 5_11_14_ and then 5_11_15_ etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things: The data you receive is *not* zero terminated, in other words you can't use it as a string. The other is that when you ask to read 25 bytes, it can read up to 25 bytes *or less*. You need to either have some sort of record-separator, or send the length beforehand.

The problem you see (the "garbage") is because of the first. The `printf` will simply fetch characters from `buf` until it hits the string terminator character `'\0'`. If it's not found then `printf` will simply continue, even reading characters from way beyond your buffer.

The simple solution to this is to increase the buffer size by one (to fit the terminator), receive one less byte than the buffer size (e.g. `sizeof(buf) - 1`), and after a successfull `read` call terminate the input:

```
buf[rd] = '\0';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. So how can I overcome this situation...I just want to avoid the garbage value...

Comment: @Haris Just added the solution